# Printing 2 values in a single foreach loop (or other solution)

Tags: c#, arrays, list, loops

I'm writing a basic program to print out the name and grade of a student (both in an array). When I try to print the array again i get an error (index is out of bounds of the array), i know what i have to print i just don't know how i should save the different array inputs and display them in a loop.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double average = 0;
        //double Hoogste = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        int i;
        Console.Write("lesson: ");
        string lesson = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("number of students: ");
        int numStudents = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        string[] names = new string[numStudents];
        int[] grade = new int[numStudents];

        for (i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("name? ");
            names[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("grade? ");
            grade[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            sum += grade[0];
            average = sum / numStudents;

        }

        foreach (string item in names) ;
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The grade of {names[i]} is {grade[]i}");
        }
```

Comment: `i get an error` ***always*** tell us what the error is so we do not have to guess

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't compile the way it is. I will give you the benefit of doubt and presume that it was a copy-paste error. I have rectified the mistakes compile time along side the ones you faced in the below code

Your main problem was that you declared the `loop variable` `i` outside the scope of the loop, which kept it available for the next loop where you print. Your print loop had a few issues. You were using a `foreach` to loop over `names` array, but using the index `i` to access the `names` array. See my code below with inline comments

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    double average = 0;
    //double Hoogste = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    //int i; // do not declare it here, this was causing you issues

    Console.Write("lesson: ");
    string lesson = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("number of students: ");
    int numStudents = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("\n");

    string[] names = new string[numStudents];
    int[] grade = new int[numStudents];

    for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) { // declare the loop variable here
        Console.Write("name? ");
        names[i] = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("grade? ");
        grade[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        sum += grade[i]; // i presume you don't want to do grade[0] but rather grade[i]
    }

    average = sum / numStudents; // I presume you don't want this line inside the for-loop, if you expect the average to be properly calculated

    //foreach (string item in names) // there was a semi-colon here by mistake, which should not be there
    for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; ++i) // you want to loop over the index
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"The grade of {names[i]} is {grade[i]}"); // i was outside the square brackets like grade[]i 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two small changes to start with:

1. The first `for` loop needs a type declared for i `for (int i = 0;` and in the `foreach` loop, `i` is out of scope so you won't be able to use it. You could probably get away with removing the `foreach` loop and put that `Console.WriteLine` at the bottom of the first foreach loop.
2. Also, check the syntax with `{grade[]i}`